# AngularJS ngHide and ngShow depending on <select> option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm trying to change the view depending on the option you select in the  tag, using ngHide/ngShow, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

**This is my current idea:**

```
<header class="hero-unit" id="banner" ng-include="'components/header/header.html'"></header>

<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>


<div class="container">
    <h3 class="site-headline">Opret nyt produkt</h3> <hr>
    <form> 
        <div class="container jumbotron">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="option in options" name="chosenOption">
                        {{ option.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div ng-show="{{ option.name }} == 'Pool'" ng-include="'new-pool.html'"></div>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<footer class="footer" ng-include="'components/footer/footer.html'"></footer>
```

bu I can't seem to access the {{ option }}, which makes sense since I'm out of the ng-repeat scope.

**I tried making this method:**

```
$scope.setProduct = function(productName){
    $scope.product = productName;
    console.log($scope.product);
};
```

And simply call the ng-change on the select tag, to set the product.name = chosenOption. It does print out the correct $scope.product but it doesn't show the ng-include.

I can't seem to wrap my head around it, and could use a helping hand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `ng-model` to `<select>`:

```
<div class="container jumbotron">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <select ng-model="selectedOption">
            <option ng-repeat="option in options" name="chosenOption">
                {{ option.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="selectedOption.name == 'Pool'" ng-include="'new-pool.html'"></div>

</div>
```

The `ng-model` on select will then be set to the currently selected object.

Comment: The I get this console error: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '==' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [== 'Pool'] starting at [== 'Pool'].`

Comment: That is because you don't need `{{ }}` inside an `ng-show`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Alright I got that sorted, but the ng-show still doesn't appear.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. I simply had to remove the ' from the `== 'Pool'`

Comment: Okay, it still doesn't quite work. For some reason the `ng-show` doesn't hide the `ng-include`. It just shows the div no matter what